# How to tell if .NET compiled code uses p/invoke?

Tags: .net, pinvoke

What is the easiest way to tell if .NET compiled code is using p/invoke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite sure the [Mono migration analyzer (MoMA)](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) can do this.

Answer (score 7):

Use reflection and look for any methods with the [DllImport] attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) if the code isn't obfuscated to view what's going on in the .dll.

Comment: Unless you're trying to do it programmatically.